# Python finding file path

Tags: python, file

```
if os.path.exists('D:\Python\New folder\'+f):
    open(f+c, 'w')
```

The f is a character that changes in a loop. How do i add it to the rest of the `'D:\Python\New folder\'` ? What i've done above makes the whole line highlighted as a comment.

Comment: Read up on raw strings and `os.path.join`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a `\` backslash as the last character, as `\'` means *use an actual quote character* rather then the end of the string.

You should really use `os.path.join()` here and have Python join the path and the filename together, and use a raw string literal for the path so that the other `\` characters don't form escape sequences (`\n` would be a newline, for example):

```
path = os.path.join(r'D:\Python\New folder', f)
if os.path.exists(path):
    open(os.path.join(path, c), 'w')
```

`os.path.join()` will add the required `\` path separators for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use python os.path module

[os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if os.path.exists('D:\Python\New folder\\'+f):
    open(f+c, 'w')
```